# Is it safe to do http requests to websites people submitted?

Tags: node.js, http

Are there any security risks if I do http GET or HEAD requests to links people submitted(so it can be absolutely anything) from my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few I can come up with:

- The attacker could setup a server that takes a long time to respond or return a bogus HTTP header that causes your thread/process to take a long time to respond, this may cause a DDOS on your system.
- The attacker my point you to link that download a huge file which would cause your system memory/hd to blow up
- Your HTTP client might have security holes in it that could be exploited by a crafted GET response

Comment: So if using just HEAD, 2nd and 3rd are not really a problem. And you can deal with 1st one with reasonable timeouts. Thank you for the answer! I'll wait a bit more and see if anyone else answers before accepting your answer.

Comment: @Errdob Yes, the slow response and the big payload scenarios are the most critical IMO. I wouldn't worry too much about the rest